# Как задать имя сохраняемого файла?

Tags: файлы, html, javascript

Есть ли возможность задать имя файла?
Нашел [статью](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download), но способ, который в ней, - не работает. Все равно сохраняет с именем, которое хранится на сервере. Есть ли другой способ? [Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/hogddttr27/7z3q1jff/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Это очень [свежая](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) возможность, работает кое-как, лучше сделайте скрипт, которому на вход будете давать путь к файлу и желаемое название, а там по старинке через "Content-Disposition".

Comment: А можно ссылку на пример?

Answer (score 1):

Надёжно это сделать на клиенте нельзя, согласно текущим стандартам. За имя файла отвечает HTTP Header `Content-Disposition`, который генерируется сервером, на который ведёт ссылка.

Что можно сделать:

1) Проставить тег `download` и надеяться, в некоторых браузерах он работает.

2) Попробовать скачать файл при помощи `XHR2`, создать новую ссылку на скаченный файл. Когда-то этот хак работал и в FF и в Хроме.

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      a = document.createElement('a'), 
      file;

xhr.open('GET', 'someFile', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    file = new Blob([xhr.response], { type : 'application/octet-stream' });
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = 'someName.gif';  // Можно проставить любое имя
    a.click();
};
xhr.send();
```